# Changing variables in data frame

Tags: r

I have the data frame as this:

```
 Sample   Protein1   X.Age
   1        4.3      25-35
   2        1.5      35-45
   3        2.6      25-35
   4        1.9      45-55
   5        4.2      35-45
```

and so on. The thing is I would like to change "35-45" and "45-55" to "35+"
This is my code

```
df$X.Age[df$X.Age == "35-45"] <- "35+"
```

But when I run it I get :

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, df$X.Age == "35-45", value = c(1L, 1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

It's weird since I can change on others factors like gender and hade the exact same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text = "Sample   Protein1   X.Age
   1        4.3      25-35
   2        1.5      35-45
   3        2.6      25-35
   4        1.9      45-55
   5        4.2      35-45", header = TRUE)

#DF$X.Age[DF$X.Age == "35-45"] <- "35+"
#warning about invalid factor levels and results in NAs
```

A `factor` is defined as a variable with a finite set of possible values (its `levels`). You can't assign it values that are not in this set. Note that functions that create a data.frame automatically change `character` columns to `factor` columns unless you change the default settings.

You have two options. Ensure that the variable is of class `character` (e.g., use the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` setting) and not a `factor` and use your code. Or change the factor levels directly:

```
levels(DF$X.Age)[levels(DF$X.Age) == "35-45"] <- "35+"
#Sample Protein1 X.Age
#1      1      4.3 25-35
#2      2      1.5   35+
#3      3      2.6 25-35
#4      4      1.9 45-55
#5      5      4.2   35+
```